# JSP <c:foreach> choose parameter to set

Tags: html, jsp, jstl, el

In my JSP page I am iterating through the list of Students and displaying them on Parent page, when I press "remove" or "edit" button it should set as parameter one of studentID which have to be edited/removed, but it set to parameter both studentID's.Here is code and some pic's:

```
<c:forEach var="thisStudent" items="${studentList}">
   <form:hidden path="studentID" value="${thisStudent.studentID}"/>
   <div class="panelheader">
      <p>${thisStudent.userName}</p>
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body fixed-panel">
         <div class="childinfo">
            <img src="resources/images/Matildacircle.png" class="center-block">
            <p>${thisStudent.firstName}</p>
            <p>Points ${thisStudent.rewardPoints} </p>
            <BR>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default center-block redeembtn">Redeem</button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
         <div class="pull-left">                                         
            <button id="removeStudent" type="submit" name="action" value="removeStudent" style="color: #32B2B2">remove</button> <span class="colortext">|</span> 
            <button id="editStudent" type="submit" name="action" value="editStudentInfo" style="color: #32B2B2">edit</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</c:forEach>
```

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple `hidden` fields rendered by the `c:forEach` tag. But you need to use only one. Therefore you should move the hidden tag out of the `c:forEach` body.

When you click on the button it triggers `click` and `submit` events that you can handle by javascript code to set the value of the hidden field with the current `strudentID`.

```jsp
<button id="editStudent" type="submit" name="action" value="editStudentInfo" style="color: #32B2B2" onclick="setStudentID(${thisStudent.studentID})">edit</button>
         </div>
<script>
  function setStudentID(studentID){
    document.forms[0].elements['studentID'].value=studentID;
  }
</script>
```

Note: the script tag you should use out

Comment: thanks for reply @Roman C, but javascript code is not executing, so studentID is not set in parameter.

Comment: why it's not executing?

Comment: It worked! I didn't inserted in code this line(out of <c:foreach>):
`<input type="hidden" path="studentID" name="studentID" />`
After I did it it worked! Thanks a lot!! It saved me a lot of time :))